# Proof involving axioms of field

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, self-learning

Given $\mathcal{F}$ is a field and $\alpha \in \mathcal{F}$. Prove that $$0+\alpha=\alpha$$

Since existence of additive identity $0$ is part of axioms, I don't understand how to prove this statement.

**EDIT: Exact Statement from Page2 of Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces:**

Almost all the laws of elementary mathematics are consequences of the axioms defining a field. Prove, in particular, that if  $\mathcal{F}$ is a field and if $\alpha$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$, then following relationship hold

$$(a) \hspace{5mm} 0+\alpha=\alpha$$

Comment: There is nothing to prove: it is an axiom.

Comment: It's possible you were given only the axiom $a+ 0 = a$, and they want you to say that $a+0 = 0+a$ because $+$ is commutative.  This would be silly of them in my opinion, but it's not impossible that's what they mean.

Comment: Actually this is first question in first exercise of Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces by Paul Halmos, so I am a bit hesitant to call it a silly question

Comment: I think this question needs more context and other details to be a meaningful one. Depending on how one interprets it, it's either trivial or unanswerable with the information given.

Comment: @ Hurkyl, I have added exact statement from book. I don't think that it is adding anything extra to the context of originally asked question